# numpy and pandas breaking after installing biopython on spyder anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I'm using spyder 2 anaconda 2.3.0 on windows as a python IDE for python 2.7. I've been using this for a long time to code in python but suddenly I don't know what happened and it said I did not have biopython package installed, when I installed biopython using 
    conda -c install anaconda biopython
command, biopython started running however it broke pandas and numpy. 
now when I import pandas I get this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in 
<module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas 
from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --
inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

and then when I import numpy I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I uninstalled numpy and pandas and then installed them back using pip ... still the same. I entirely unistalled anaconda and installed it back still the same errors. I really do not know what's causing this. Any help will be truly appreciated. I've been trying to fix this for the past three days and its not working out. Thanks for your time.

Comment: i think your installations are jumbled up together with different conda and pip installs. I would suggest for try things in virtual environment and see if this reproducible. If not then installation went awry and you need to reinstall things.

Comment: I think that might've been the cause. I don't know what exactly had happened but I uninstalled anaconda and installed the newer version (anaconda 5) and it's working properly now.